# How to encode a two-dimensional boolean array to a one-dimensional array and later decode it in java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, boolean

I'm using an one-dimensional byte array to store blob data on an sqlite database.

I'm looking for a fast and clean way of converting two-dimensional boolean arrays (boolean [][]) to one-dimensional byte arrays (byte[]) and then back.

I can use any external libraries and temporary arrays.

The only idea I've had is to encode the 2D array into a 1D string array as outer array indexes separated from the value by a dash or other unique sign, then converted into bytes (as that would eliminate the dimensional incompatibility), but that does not seem optimal.

Are there any good, clean ways of doing this operation?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this ..https://java.achchuthan.org/2011/12/how-to-convert-two-dimensional-array.html

Comment: We expect you to have attempted the problem before asking. Seeing as you have an idea for an implementation, I suggest you try it and *actually profile it*. Saying something doesn't "seem optimal" is fairly meaningless, and you don't require it to be so. You require it to be *good enough* for your application. Conjecture, but I'd say the I/O to the disk has a fairly good chance of being the limiting factor anyway.

Comment: What does “converting two-dimensional boolean arrays to one-dimensional byte arrays” actually mean?  What would the byte representation of `{ true, true, false, false, true, false, true, false }` look like?  A single byte with the value `0b11001010`?  A sequence of bytes, `{ 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0 }`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need some kind of coding/decoding declaration in your code. So if I were you I would make something like this.

Given:

- N-dimensional array [i] [j] [k] ... [n];
- Binary number with the length equals to the number of dimensions (N);

Imagine having the 2D array:

```
    1       2 

1 [true]  [true] 

2 [false] [false]
```

One dimension could be coded from left to right or from right to left. For instance I'll take right to left.
The result array should be like

```
[0b01] [0b01]
```

The code:

```
class Encoder {

    private static final byte START_MASK  = 0b01;

    public byte[] code(boolean[][] arr) {
        int length = arr.length;
        byte[] result = new byte[length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            byte mask = START_MASK;
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                result[i] = (byte) (result[i] | (arr[j][i] ? mask : 0));
                mask = (byte) (mask << 2);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    public boolean[][] decode(byte[] arr) {
        int length = arr.length;
        boolean[][] result = new boolean[length][length];

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            byte mask = START_MASK;
            for (int j = 0; j < length; j++) {
                result[j][i] = (mask & arr[i]) == mask;
                mask = (byte) (mask << 2);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to run this on an array of size 11x20, and seeing your code, i'm running into issues when i'm exceeding that length, because it needs 20 and only has 11. Does this only work on square arrays?

Comment: Give me a few mins, I've made a mistake. I'll update this answer

Comment: In encoding, we're still using the same length for both i and j which still gives errors when j is smaller than i.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking I discovered that it is simpler to encode to string instead of trying to encode to bytes. This is supported by SQLite and thus achieves my goal. Here's the code i used to do it. It also supports varying sizes of sub-arrays. I'm not certain about exceeding maximum string length though.

```
public static String Bool2DToString(boolean[][] arr){

    String result = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(i > 0){result += ":";}
        for(int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
            if(arr[i][j]){
                result += "1";
            } else {
                result += "0";
            }
        }
    }

    return result;

}

public static boolean[][] StringToBool2D(String str){

    String[] splitstr = str.split(":");

    boolean[][] result = new boolean[splitstr.length][splitstr[0].length()];

    for(int i = 0; i < splitstr.length; i++){
        char[] a = splitstr[i].toCharArray();
        for(int j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
            if(a[j] == '1'){
                result[i][j] = true;
            } else {
                result[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;

}
```